# Ubuntu freezes after update to 21.10

Tags: freeze, 21.10

I upgraded from 21.04 to 21.10 and it was awesome, super cool, but then I shat down the computer and the next day when I turn it on it freezes after I log in. Not even the power off button works, i have to hold it so it completely Turns off. After trying many times to reboot it, I noticed that some times it freezes before it even powers up, when there’s the HP logo and the Ubuntu word. Other times it freezes later. I think it has something to do with configuration files, because I edited them to make the dock cool. How can I solve this? Possibly without reinstalling everything

Edit
I have only changed dash-to-dock, and in some of my attempts i did login, i also tried to open firefox but it freezed while it was loading

Edit 2
In var/log/syslog most of the lines say rtw_8821ce pci bus timeout and some lines say
Gnome-shell: the xkeyboard Keymap compiler (xkbcomp) reports:
Warning unsupported maximum key code 569, clipping
X11 cannot support key codes above 255
Errors from xkbcomp are not fatal to the x server
chrome …… corruption detected in extension ….
Chrome ……. Warning: chrome_content_verifier_delegate.cc corruption detected …..
And then other chrome and opera corruption errors

This kinda makes sense because it was when I tried to use a browser that it freezed

Edit 3
Sudo dmesg -T gives me this https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/T2FZ4mJMyF/

I installed openssh server so I could login from another device once it freezes but I noticed that when it’s freezed I can’t ssh in it

I also tried with alt+f2 and then r to restart the gnome desktop but no success

I also updated the packages but nothing

Comment: @user535733 I have only changed dash-to-dock,  and in some of my attempts i did login, i also tried to open firefox but it freezed while it was loading, so i don't think it's that.

Comment: @user535733 Ok I’ll edit it now. Anyway, I just tried again and it’s not freezing but i checked the logs and they’re like a lot, like hundreds per second, is it normal?

Comment: Big, long logs? Sure, that's normal. That's what makes it useful. Note the *exact* time of a freeze in order to look at that part of the log -- which might mean after your next freeze. Or you look for ERROR messages in the log. They are not hidden -- developers *want* folks to find error messages.

Comment: I added what the logs say @user535733

Comment: If your system is freezing before login sometimes, then all the Gnome Shell and X server issues are spurious, since they do not run before login. Is this a laptop or is it a desktop with separate monitor/keyboard/mouse components? Does it have a graphics/video card?

Comment: Yes this is also happening to me, I don't have the dash to dock extension, but I have pixel saver . The freeze always occur when login in and half way the animation to show the desk. Edit: in the gdm change to Ubuntu with xorg, that's how I fixed it. I un installed the extension and now works. Maybe you could try disabling some extensions one by one and see how reacts

Comment: How do you change it?

Comment: *but then I shat down the computer* I'm surprised its still booting at all ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out that it was somewhat related to the WiFi adapter driver. The new kernel didn’t work, but the old one did.

I replaced my driver to this https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce and now it also works with the new kernel.

To install the driver open a terminal and type

1. `sudo apt update`
2. `git clone https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce`
3. `cd rtl8821ce`
4. `sudo ./dkms-install.sh`

Comment: Your answer is accepted and looks like it solved the issue , but actually it doesn't look like that it is even helpful at all except telling to **download a new driver** , So please [edit] your answer to add that which driver should be downloaded , and how to download that driver to make it a little easier to understand

Comment: As specified in  https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce README, I also blacklisted rtw88_8821ce kernel module.

In `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` add:

```blacklist rtw88_8821ce```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem after adding the DKMS drivers worked for me. No more freeze-ups.
Menu -> Administrations -> "Software & Updates" -> "Additional Drivers" -> select: "Realtek Semiconductor RTL8821CE 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter"